# Obtener JSON con PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

Estoy tratando de obtener por medio de cURL un JSON, pero quiero que me muestre solo las variables de ese JSON; el JSON que debe mostrar es el siguiente:

```
{
"resultado": {
    "codigo": 200,
    "error": "OK"
    }
}
```

yo solamente quiero obtener el código, que muestre algo asi como "Código: 200"

Pero me muestra "Código: "

El código PHP es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$url = "https://test.efactura.com.uy:64431/efactura/ping";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
if($e=curl_error($curl)){
    echo $e;
}else{
    $json=json_decode($resp, true); 
    var_dump($json);
    echo "<br>Código: ".$json['codigo'];
    echo "<br>Error: ".$json['error'];
}
curl_close($curl);  
?>
```

Comment: No estoy del todo seguro, pero no debería ir el `$json->codigo` y `$json->error` de esta manera?

Answer (score 2):

yo lo intentaría así :

```
<?php
$respuesta = array();
$url = "https://test.efactura.com.uy:64431/efactura/ping";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
if($e=curl_error($curl)){
    echo $e;
}else{
    $json=json_decode($resp, true); 
    var_dump($json);
    $respuesta['cod']= $json['codigo'];
    $respuesta['err']=$json['error'];
}
curl_close($curl);  
echo json_encode($respuesta);
?>
```

Comment: Si, pero yo lo debo hacer con cURL

Comment: Edité la respuesta aplicando mi sugerencia a tu situación, espero te sirva